# How to attach image in email in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, email-attachments

I am trying to attach image in email and also want that image will also in the body of the email.I am using it in Console programme.

```
$Email = new CakeEmail('default');
            $Email->template('default', 'default')                   
                  ->to($user_email)
                  ->attachments(array(
                            array(         
                                    'file' => ROOT . '/app/webroot/img/logo-02.png',
                                    'mimetype' => 'image/png',
                                    'contentId' => 'cid:135'
                                                   ),
                            ))
                 ->subject('Your Daily Tasks')
                 ->send($email_body);                
        }
```

In layout file i tried this.

```
<img border=0 width=160 height=60  src="cid:135">
```

My this code only attaching the image  and did not put it in the body of the email body.Please highlight it where i am going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contentId` key should contain only the ID, the `cid` scheme name should only be used in your HTML image tags `src` attributes.

```
'contentId' => '12345'
```

```
<img src="cid:12345">
```

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments**